# Bulk Import Category With Heirachy

Tags: magento-1.8, category, import

I'm still a Beginner in Magento and I was given a task to upload/create 600 Categories and have a hierarchy up to 4th subcategory. I've been searching for a while now, and most return paid extensions. Would someone be kind enough to help me perform this or point me to a guide? So far I have found a random script; it ran well with no errors yet still didn't create any category.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are not able to do this task, look for some one who teaches it to you. Magento offers great courses with awesome teachers ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I've created a script for this last weekend. It works on a simple text file and white spaces to indicate hierarchy. Just make sure the Root category exists and the name is correct.

Run the scripts from a subdirectory in your web root directory (the directory you've installed Magento in) preferably using SSH and not through a webbrowser.

This should take away most of your work.

https://github.com/sandermangel/magento-dummy-installers

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [nice extension](http://www.magentoworks.net/magento-extension) (look for "Import/Export Magento Category Extension" in the page) that can import/export a tree of categories.
You have to build a csv file with your categories in a specific format (nothing fancy though) and place it in a folder of your magento instance, then run some actions in the admin.
I don't really like the fact that the source file must be placed on the disk , but with some small changes it can be changed to accept a file upload.

Answer (score 1):

Creating categories is quite easy. Have a look on

```
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api_V2::create($parentId, $categoryData, $store = null)
```

So create a structure to create the categories in the right order

- 1st level
- 2nd level
- etc.

Remember the ids and use them as `$parentId`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quick-script-batch-create-magento-categories/

Answer (score 1):

I too just recently wrote a category import. The setPath() method was the key to my situation.

```
     $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->setName($catName)
    ->setPath($catPath)
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS')
    ->setIsAnchor(1)
    ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
    ->save();
```

Prior to that code I build each category a Path of category ids, starting with the base like so:

```
$catPath = '1/2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my tutorial here I am explaining how to create category and subcategories using the magento script.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-the-categories-programmatically/

I am pasting some sample code here.The $import_category array contain the data.

```
foreach ($arrResult as $import_category) {
    try {
        if (strtolower($import_category[16]) == 'true') {
            $enabled = 1;
        } else {
            $enabled = 0;
        }

        if ($import_category[1] == 0) {
            $parentId = '2';
        }
        else {
            $parentId = $list[$import_category[1]];
        }

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($import_category[2]);
        $category->setMetaTitle($import_category[2]);
        $category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
        $category->setUrlKey($import_category[10]);
        $category->setDescription(strip_tags($import_category[11]));
        $category->setMetaDescription($import_category[12]);
        $category->setMetaKeywords($import_category[13]);
        $category->setIsActive($enabled);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $category->setCustomUseParentSettings(true);
        $category->setImage($import_category[6]);
        $category->save();
        $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
        echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
        print_r($e);
    }
```