# Import new products and new categories using import product CSV file (Magento CE 1.9)?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

I want to import new products and new categories to my Magento CE 1.9 store. I want to import them all at once using Magento's native import function. During this action the new products need to be assigned to the newly created categories.

Can I do this by uploading a single CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT:** Each Magento store is different. The .csv files have a specific structure that must match the database of your store!

[image: Magento product import .csv file]

So the best thing you could possibly do is to create your own Magento product import .csv file by exporting the product data from your own store first. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Login to your Magento Admin Panel
2. Go to `System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Pofiles`
3. Open the **"Export All Products"** profile and configure it according to your needs/preferences
4. After saving the profile go to the **"Run Profile"** tab and press the **"Run Profile in Popup"** button, this will save the export .csv file
5. Now use your FTP program or file manager to download this file to your computer. By default the export file is called **"export_all_products.csv"** and located in the `var/export/` folder
6. Open this file on your local computer using an appropriate program, make changes/add your products and save it

To import the products using this new .csv file:

1. Go to `System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Pofiles` again
2. Open the **"Import All Products"** profile, configure it according to your needs/preferences and save the profile
3. Go to the **"Upload File"** tab and browse for the modified .csv file you just saved on your computer and save the profile once again to upload this .csv file
4. Finally, head over to the **"Run Profile"** tab, select the .csv file that you have uploaded in the previous step and click on the **"Run Profile in Popup"** button. Your products import .csv file will then be processed.
5. After completion of the import you should see a success message

[Here's the the link](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#store-operations/data-csv-files.html) to the original Magento User Guide documentation on how to work with .csv files when operation a Magento store.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Secondly, I have tried to use your method, it looks like if I have to import the product category, and then import the product, so I have to use two csv file. The steps will be more cumbersome. Now I want to use a csv file (containing product information and product categories),  how do I  use a csv file to import product information and product categories information? THX!

Comment: I don't think the Data Profiles allow you to import categories and their hierarchy. But I do believe that the import file should assign products to existing categories. In my export .csv file there is a column called `category_ids` which contains the Category ID per product. To import categories you may want to check out [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11143/bulk-import-category-with-heirachy) and the link provided in the answar by [Marius](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I have to import the product categories firstly, and then manually edit one classification corresponds to the product,and finally I was able to import the corresponding product classification. Magento should be a more powerful system, and 
Why it can not be a one-time import of products (including product  categories, pictures)?