# Import Group products in Magento

Tags: importexport

we want to import group products in our website through CSV , 
Pleas guide us what will be the format of CSV to import group products.

Comment: which version are you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using magento 2 u can just go to system--> import and u can generate a sample csv there. Another method is to create a couple of products and then export them and adjust that list. it takes some knowledge but i can advise u this :

-> when u use excel --> open again in notepad++ and convert to UTF8 with DOM before uploading

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9 version and need to import group products.

Comment: For magento 1.9 its about the same. see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75641/import-new-products-and-new-categories-using-import-product-csv-file-magento-ce

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Please refer the tutorial for the full code.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-grouped-products-magento-2/

```
$associated = array();
$position = 0;

foreach($childrenIds as $productId) {
    $position++;
    $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $linkedProduct = $productRepository->getById($productId);
    $productLink = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface');
    $productLink->setSku($product->getSku())
        ->setLinkType('associated')
        ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
        ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
        ->setPosition($position)
        ->getExtensionAttributes()
        ->setQty(0);
    $associated[] = $productLink;     
}
$product->setProductLinks($associated);
$product->save();
```